# Checking empty form elements in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple client-side, self-grading quiz.

I ask 6 questions and I want to alert the user with their score (keeping things simple).  If they leave an answer blank, an alert will appear.

I'm new to javascript and don't really know how to check individual form elements to see if they're empty. I'm also having problems with getting my code to run.

**JS**

***EDIT***

```
function grade() {
    var score = 0;
    var elt = document.quiz;

    // Check to see if no questions were left unanswered.
    if elt.question1.value.length == 0 || elt.question2.value.length == 0 ||   
       elt.question3.value.length == 0 || elt.question4.value.length == 0 ||
       elt.question5.value.length == 0 || elt.question6.value.length == 0
      {
        alert ("Whoops, you're missing an answer!")
    }

    if (elt.question1[1].checked) {
        score += 1;
    }
    if (elt.question2[0].checked) {
        score += 1;
    }
    if (elt.question3[0].checked == false && elt.question3[1].checked &&  
        elt.question3[2].checked == false && elt.question3[3].checked == false) {
        score += 1;
    }
    if (elt.question4[0].checked == false && elt.question4[1].checked == false &&
        elt.question4[2].checked == false && elt.question4[3].checked) {
        score += 1;
    }
    elt.question5 = elt.question5.toLowerCase()
    if (elt.question5.value != '' && elt.question5.value.indexOf('galaxy') != -1) {
        score += 1;
    }
    elt.question6 = elt.question6.toLowerCase()
    if (elt.question5.value != '' && elt.question6.value.indexOf('age') != -1) {
        score += 1;
    }

    score = score / 6 * 100;
    score = score.toFixed(2);
    alert("You scored " + score + "%");

    return false; // Return true if you want the form to submit on validation/grade
}
```

Comment: Markup "cleaned up": http://jsfiddle.net/BeD3Z/4/

Comment: Please don't put spaces between attributes, the `=`, and the quoted value for the attribute. `:)`

Comment: @Jared Thanks for cleaning it up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a some significant errors in your markup:

1. Do not wrap a `form` element around each question. These should all be in one `form` element. (Also, each question be in a `OL` to number the question in series.)
2. You're not properly closing all of your `label`'s, so they're selecting other elements when you click them (try question 3, first checkbox).
3. You need the `grade()` function on the form's `submit` handler, and it needs to be `onsubmit="return grade()"`, with `grade()` returning `false` when it doesn't "pass" to prevent form submission*.

* Note, I set the `grade()` function to *always* `return false` in the example. You would need to add the logic for when it would allow the form to submit.

As far as the Javascript...

You need the `elt` variable to be equal to your `document.quiz` (note, I changed the main `form` to have a `name="quiz"` in your markup). You can use `indexOf()` instead of a regex if you just want to have a simple check (regex could check for `age` as a word, though).

If you just want to make sure a text input is not empty, you can use `el.value.length != 0` or `el.value != ''`.

Also, looking at your grading code, if you want only one to be selected, you could use a radio, unless you want the person taking the quiz to not know if one or more were valid answers. But radio's only allow you to select a single value.

**HTML**

```
<h3> Self-Grading Astronomy Quiz </h3>
<form action="" name="quiz" onsubmit="return grade();">
 <p>1. According to Kepler the orbit of the earth is a circle with the sun at the center.</p>
 <p>
  <label><input type="radio" name="question1" value="true" /> True </label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="question1" value="false" /> False </label>
 </p>
 <p>2. Ancient astronomers did consider the heliocentric model of the solar system but rejected it because they could not detect parallax.</p>
 <p>
  <label><input type="radio" name="question2" value="true" /> True </label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="question2" value="false" /> False </label>
 </p>
 <p>3. The total amount of energy that a star emits is directly related to its:</p>
 <p>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="question3" value="1" /> a) surface gravity and magnetic field </label><br/>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="question3" value="2" /> b) radius and temperature </label><br/>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="question3" value="3" /> c) pressure and volume </label><br/>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="question3" value="4" /> d) location and velocity </label>
 </p>
 <p>4. Stars that live the longest have:</p>
 <p>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="question4" value="1" /> a) high mass </label><br/>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="question4" value="2" /> b) high temperature </label><br/>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="question4" value="3" /> c) lots of hydrogen </label><br/>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="question4" value="4" /> d) small mass </label>
 </p>
 <p>5. A collection of a hundred billion stars, gas, and dust is called a __________.</p>
 <p>
  <input type='text' id='question5' />
 </p>
 <p>6. The inverse of the Hubble's constant is a measure of the __________ of the universe.</p>
 <p>
  <input type='text' id='question6' />
 </p>
 <p>
  <input type='button' onclick='grade()' value='Grade' />
 </p>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
function grade() {
    //**Would I do something like this?
    //if(elem.value.length == 0){
    // alert("Whoops, looks like you didn't answer a question.")}
    var score = 0;
    var elt = document.quiz;

    if (elt.question1[1].checked) {
        score += 1;
    }
    if (elt.question2[0].checked) {
        score += 1;
    }
    if (elt.question3[0].checked == false && elt.question3[1].checked && elt.question3[2].checked == false && elt.question3[3].checked == false) {
        score += 1;
    }
    if (elt.question4[0].checked == false && elt.question4[1].checked == false && elt.question4[2].checked == false && elt.question4[3].checked) {
        score += 1;
    }
    if (elt.question5.value != '' && elt.question5.value.indexOf('galaxy') != -1) {
        score += 1;
    }
    if (elt.question5.value != '' && elt.question6.value.indexOf('age') != -1) {
        score += 1;
    }

    score = score / 6 * 100;
    score = score.toFixed(2);
    alert("You scored " + score + "%");

    return false; // Return true if you want the form to submit on validation/grade
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BeD3Z/10/

Comment: Thanks!  One last question though, when using el.value.length != 0, it would look something like this: if (question1.value.length != 0){alert("error");} correct?

Comment: Hey Jared, sorry for the barrage of questions but I have one more...I updated my jsfiddle to include a line of code that looks for any possible empty answers.  I also added toLowerCase() to both questions 5 and 6 incase the user uses uppercase characters.  Somehow when I did all this, I screwed up the code because now it doesn't work.  Mind checking it out?  Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't seem to update.  I'm adding my JS to my original post.

Comment: You'll need to give me the link (I won't know otherwise). Also, my aunt happened to work on the Kepler space craft (she's an engineer at NASA).

Comment: @Rich2233 - See the fiddle at the bottom of my answer. Use *this one* to work from. `:)`

Comment: Updated the fiddle below your answer with the JS function.  Also put it in my original post as an edit.  That's awesome to hear about your Aunt!  Kepler is one sweet project!

Comment: @Rich2233 - First, right at the beginning you have `if elt...`. You need parentheses around the conditional (`if (thisstuff !== thatstuff)`, other words). Also, when you say `elt.question5 = elt.question5.toLowerCase()`, this isn't right simply because `elt.question5` is an element *reference*, not a value. Instead, do `elt.question5.value.toLowerCase().indexOf('galaxy')` in the conditional on the next line. And... even though JS doesn't force you to end each statement in a `;`, please do anyways.

Comment: Check out http://jsfiddle.net/rich2233/HSrDB/1/  I made your suggested changes, but still can't get it to start working.

Comment: That's because you're not understanding how to use jsfiddle. See on the top, left, under **Choose Framework**? You have `onLoad` and `MooTools`. These should be `no wrap (head)` and `No-Library (Pure JS)`. Also, you're checking for elements that are essentially arrays (inputs of type radio and checkbox), so there is no `.value` per se. See: http://jsfiddle.net/HSrDB/2/

Answer (score 1):

> check individual form elements to see if they're empty

You just compare the value to an empty string:

```
if(elt.question6.value == '') {
  alert('Unanswered');
}
```

Comment: Will this work for the multiple choice and true/false or only for the short answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquerys built in validation http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation. It has built in functionality to check for required and to display an error message below the field which is blank.

Comment: Jquerys validation has everything under the sun and if there is something you don't see, there is functionality to add your own custom validation. Very cool stuff.